# Simple insertion through asp MVC3 EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

i have two simple models that have one-many relation

```
public class X{
  public int id {get;set;}
  public virtual Y y{ get; set; }
  public string description{get;set;}
}
public class Y{
  public int id{get;set;}
  public string name{get;set;}
}
```

and from the entity framework i set the relation

I'm trying to submit a form that creates a new `X` record with existing `Y` value

the returned data from the form to the action is the `string description` and `y_id`.

on the action when i try to specify the object from the parameters

```
public ActionResult sth(X x){}
```

the `x.y` is set to null (which is expected...) while when i tried the following ...

```
x.y = (from i in Y where i.id == that_id select i).first(); 
...
db.saveChanges();
```

the entity framework inserted a new `Y` record to the database ...

i know that i'm doing something wrong ... your help will be very appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems an issue with tracking Y objects in the dbContext. how are you generating the collection Y you querying with linq? do you fetch it from the database using a dbContext? or from some other source?

if not, you need to be fetching it using a context or using the Attach() function so it could be properly tracked.

Another question pops up. how come a new Y is inserted? Don't you have a primary key defined in the database? or is it try to insert then an exception is thrown?

These are my thoughts on the matter.

Comment: sir, the `y` is generated by linq query from the same db context, and for the insertion the ID is db identity was replaced with a new one... I'll try the attach method and see what will happen

Comment: Sir, the attach method worked perfectly, just can you please tell me why this issue occurred and is it because the `y` is virtual member (it was not attached to the controller db context ) ? thanks alot Sir,

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the code you have an ID for x and y with a Virtual Y in x. Along with this Virtual Y in x you will also need a reference to y's id. Along with a Virtual ICollection of x in y.

```
public class X{
  public int x_id {get;set;}
  public int y_id {get;set}
  public virtual Y y{ get; set; }
  public string description{get;set;}
}
public class Y{
  public int y_id{get;set;}
  public string name{get;set;}
  public virtual ICollection<X> X {get;set;}
}
```

This helps the relationship in entity. You may also want to pass a list of y(s) to the controller in charge of your form, unless you already selecting your y value from a dropdown on the form.

Comment: sir, when i did the following the migration script was going to rename the column from `("y_id")` to `("Y_id1")` and add a new column called `"Y_id"`

Comment: Not had much experience with Migrations yet, though depending on what stage your application is in you may want to look at Dropping and Recreating the database when you make changes to the model, it aids with rapid development and avoid Migrations until you reach a deployment stage. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3 should tell you how.

Comment: Sir, my DB has huge amount of data, i cant on every change do recreation and refilling to the DB, if you disagree please till me.

Comment: Hmmm, fair point. I'm not really sure I'm afraid on Migrations. My answer stands for this question though, the best, if not only way, to get the relationship you require is to store Y's id in X. The auto generated View and Controller should then make it very simple to assign Ys value to X.

Comment: as a backup plan I'll use this ... but just want to double check if there is another way ... thanks alot sir, really thanks for your time ...